# New kernel version not coming in grub menu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, kernel

Last kernel 5.0.0.23 is showing this error[init not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO94I.jpg)

Kernel 5.0.0.21 working fine, using it currently,

I did a system update which installed 5.0.0.25 but it's not visible in grub menu.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufkRu.png)

also ran  grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg    but nothing happened.

how to boot into kernel 5.0.0.25?
& why latest kernel version is not showing in grub menu

Comment: It looks like your system believes you are using UEFI to boot and not GRUB.  Try going into your UEFI boot loader and see if you can boot it from there.

Comment: not getting , how to it?